# Is $eA$ simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ be an algebra and $e$ be a primitive idempotent of $A$. We know that $eA$ is indecomposable as a right $A$-module. Is $eA$ a simple right $A$-module? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about if $A$ is an integral domain, so that $e = 1$.  Then $e A= A$, but $A$ is simple as a module over itself only if it is a field.